# Lua Library for Jabber

Tags: lua, xmpp

Does anyone know of a Jabber library for Lua?  I've found the 'Lua Messaging Library' for AIM, although I can't find a download for it, it appears to be abandoned.

Something like that for Lua would be helpful.

---

I'm sorry I didn't state this originally, I meant a 'pure Lua' library.

I'm familiar with Verse, but don't have the option of building my own Lua distribution for this particular application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a bit of a follow-up, I'm the author of both Prosody and Verse. I'm in the process of updating Verse to use the new code developed for Prosody, and as such Verse will become a "pure Lua" XMPP library descended from it.

It will of course need to depend on the usual LuaSocket, LuaExpat, etc. but no generated bindings will be involved as is currently the case.

Answer (score 2):

[Verse](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/verse/verse_doc.xml).

> Verse is a Jabber/XMPP library for Lua. It is based on the C version of the strophe library.
>
> One handy feature of verse is that only the core protocol is implemented by default. Extensions to the protocol (either XEPs, or custom-made protocols) can be 'described', and then used by any verse application. It is the developer's intention to include support for as many XEPs as possible with verse, any number of which can be optionally loaded by the application when initialising the library.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is [Prosody](http://prosody.im/) which is a LUA XMPP server: it may give you a head-start.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, similar needs here: I want to do XMPP messaging with the VideoLan (VLC) software, which has LUA built-in... http://jpeg.dinauz.org/blog/index.php?post/2010/01/30/Extensions-in-VLC&pub=1#pr ... so I look forward to the updated Verse work!

Answer (score 0):

"Pure Lua" has no network capability. Any XMPP library you'll find will by definition require a compiled extension.